# How to fix the header of HTML page using css

Tags: html, css

I have a header in my webpage which i need to fix it so that the user can see it from every position of the webpage but have tried to put `position:fixed` but its not working in my case.

Here is my HTML for the header.Inside this HTML tag i have putted Header Menus.

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
 //Menu item HTML
</div>
```

Here is the css for the Header div..

```
.header-wrapper {
position:fixed;
top: 0px;
left:0px;
background: url("../img/new_images/header_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
z-index: 10000;    
width: 100%;
height: 77px;
}
```

I have posted the basic HTML and Css involved .If anything else is need for more clarity of the post.Please let me know it.

Please help me.

Comment: What's not working for you?

Comment: Seems to be working just fine. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KkHny

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen My header menu bar is not not fixed .I want it to be always visible to the visitor of the site

Comment: Works here http://jsbin.com/bocoyinu/1/. Can you reproduce this with a jsFiddle (seems to be down) or jsbin?

Comment: Is there any way you can provide us with a URL to the full code? The code you posted works, which leads me to believe there might be a piece of code you left out causing your issue.

Comment: @j08691 Ok ! its working fine with Google Chrome but not in mozilla.What i should do for it

Comment: @Mastrianni Ok its working fine in Chrome but not in mozilla.Any help

Comment: What version of mozilla, you are using. I can see http://jsbin.com/bocoyinu/1 working in FF as well

Comment: Works for me in FF too.

Comment: OK Reso;lved Thanks al

Answer (score 0):

If your other content is behind the header you can solve it like this:

```
body { padding-top: 77px; }
```

This adds 77px to the top `<body>`, the rest of your content is lower but your header is still at its original position. Alternatively you can lower the next element 77px lower using:

```
#next.element.selector { position:relative; top:77px; } /* OR */
#next.element.selector { margin-top:77px; } /* OR */
#next.element.selector { padding-top:77px; }
```

If you want to know more about the box model and positioning, you can read about it [here](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/opening-the-box-model/) and [here](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/positioning-content/)